# MPMoviePlayerController setCurrentPlaybackRate not working

Tags: iphone, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

We have an http stream running on iPad iOS 4.3.3.
We are using MPMoviePlayerController. I am trying to change the playback rate in order to implement a custom fast forward experience by using:

```
[player setCurrentPlaybackRate:2.0];
```

But it isn't working. If I display the current playback rate immediately after the above line of code, it displays 1.0 only. Any idea if this doesn't work for a stream? The documentation doesn't say anything about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property `currentPlaybackRate` does indeed not work when using HTTP-streaming. I would suggest you to file a bug report to Apple on this issue. Still I assume it will not work in the future but possibly another bug report motivates them Apple folks to update their documentation accordingly.